# mapping fonts in spring project issue

Tags: css, spring, fonts, stylesheet, font-face

I've faced the next problem: I created spring project, added scripts, styles and fonts to it, mapped the resources, but fonts are not connected. here is firebug console:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/myApp/resources/fonts/cabin-regular.woff"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/myApp/resources/fonts/cabin-regular.ttf"
```

images and etc. is loaded correctly, so i don't where to look for a problem.
here is part of my css file, where I connect fonts:

```
@import url(reset.css);

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Cabin-Regular, sans-serif;
    color: #472c7f;
}
a:hover{

}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cabin-Regular';
    src: url('../fonts/cabin-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/cabin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/cabin-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/cabin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/cabin-regular.svg#cabin-regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

also i can provide contexts if needed.
I'll pleased with any pieces of advice or answers.
thanks!

UPD:

the file structure is like this:

```
/resources

             /fonts

             /styles

             /images
```

etc.

Comment: If it's a Windows machine, it could be a case sensitivity/insensitivity mismatch - try to rename these files to something completely different to rule it out.

Comment: @axtavt i should just to rename these files or to rename both files and their extensions(thus to make windows not to see them)??

Comment: Simple things first. Does your CSS directory definitely sit at the same level in your directry structure as your FONTS directory?

Comment: @BillyMoat see question update

Comment: If you put this into your browser does it find the file? http://localhost:8080/myApp/resources/styles/reset.css

Comment: @BillyMoat yep, it shows me the inner content of the file

Comment: Your fonts are named properly? `cabin-regular.eot`?

Comment: @NickB yes, they are named properly.

Comment: Put it up somewhere to test online. Make it easier to debug.

Comment: @NickB i don't think it's a good idea, cause i'm writing my application in eclipse, so there are no online services, that are able to reproduce the real conditions of my app

Comment: 404 means it isn't there, it's that simple.  Your code and paths do not match.

Comment: actually, I've checked them and they DID match

Answer (score 0):

First off, check your FTP to see if it's changed the filetype or removed the extension completely. Some FTP apps and servers behave in the same way as windows and hides the extension making your paths incorrect.

Other than that, try passing your font through the Font Face Generator on [Fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com) and remember to select base64. Base64 will, in short, embed the entire font in your CSS, and allow most browsers to recreate it without linking to an actual font-file. The drawback is that your css will increase quite a bit in size, due to the amount of data added by a base64 encoded font. Remember to select all formats you need on fontsquirrel, not only base64.